# Why get a fail test in First Posts review when we want comment to improve the post?

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits

I recently earned the privilege to review First Posts, so I tried it a little. I passed a test once and I got a case where I [failed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/14513919). I think it is very good to have a system to test people like me who are beginner in reviewing.

In my opinion, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40932844/constructor-inheritance-and-direct-member-initialisation) is not bad, but can be improved:

1. The title "Constructor inheritance and direct member initialisation" doesn't reflect the question "So my question is now, is this valid C++ 11?". The title should be more precise and mention the compile error.
2. The error log is contained in a code format, but [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276966/quote-formatting-messing-up-how-to-handle-format-of-error-logs) advises to use quote format.
3. The users edited his question, but he added "Edit" and "2nd edit:". In my opinion it's unnecessary to add that when editing a question. This information is already present in edit log of the question.

[This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work) say that tests are auto-generated. I think it's a mistake. A test should be written by a human, especially a test to test a human.

Like I say, I don't say that this post is bad. It's a good post for a new user. So I wanted to leave a comment asking him to improve his post. Why is it considered to be a failed test when I leave a comment?

Comment: For the second and third points, don't comment, edit.

Comment: @CodyGray We could imagine a new privilege to add a real post that produces a good test. So the test base will be growing with time.

Comment: Yes, that would work, if we could also imagine the people who would be willing to put in the effort to identify and curate tests. We already waste enough time slogging through posts in the queue. Why would we want to make *more* work for humans?

Comment: @CodyGray You don't actually need very many audits.  ~2 audits (per queue) per day.  That combined with some searches to identify at least possible candidates (searches that would functionally be the existing audit criteria) would mean that a single person could likely take care of that in just a few minutes each day (or more likely, a bit longer once a week to queue up a week's worth of audits)..

Comment: @CodyGray: I ran the numbers in [my post asking for this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284412/manual-audit-validation-to-create-highly-reusable-unambiguous-audits); as Servy suggests, it really does not require an enormous amount of work, even being extremely conservative to avoid potential problems.

Comment: Don't ping me; I'm not maintaining the list of volunteers. All you're saying is that it isn't *that much* more work. Okay, fine. Prove that we have people willing to do it, and that it is necessary, and I'll support it. Of course, I still won't be willing to give even a few more minutes each day. I'd rather have that time to do things I consider to be more productive.